# Extending The Controller Class in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have `class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller` and common logic for big profile section, so I'va tried to create `class Profile extends MY_Controller` with common logic for profile section and all class related to this section should extends this Profile class as I understand right, but when I tried to create `class Index extends Profile` I recieve an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Profile' not found
```

CodeIgniter tries to find this class in `index.php` which I am running.

Where is my mistake? Or maybe there is anoter better way to mark out common logic?

Comment: I asked the same question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982187/codeigniter-extending-common-controller

Hope it helps

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I take it you have put your MY_Controller in /application/core, and set the prefix in the config.
I would be careful about using index as a class name though. As a function/method in Codeigniter it has a dedicated behaviour.

If you then want to extend that controller you need to put the classes in the same file.

E.g. In /application core

```
/* start of php file */
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    }
...
}

class another_controller extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    }
...
}
/* end of php file */
```

In /application/controllers

```
class foo extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    }
...
}
```

or

```
class bar extends another_controller {
    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that methods in `MY_Controller` should _likely_ be prefixed with `_`, so that CI doesn't route them (since, by nature all methods you want to share with all controllers must be public).

Comment: Surely the shared methods can be protected instead of public. So they won't get routed, but will be accessible by the extending controllers.

Answer (score 7):

A solution that doesn't require copy/pasting the parent class into all your controller classes:

1. Place your parent class in the `core` folder.
2. Place an include statement at the beginning of all classes that include the parent class.

So a typical controller might look like this:

```
<?php

require_once APPPATH . 'core/Your_Base_Class.php';
// must use require_once instead of include or you will get an error when loading 404 pages

class NormalController extends Your_Base_Class
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        
        // authentication/permissions code, or whatever you want to put here
    }

    // your methods go here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It is possible with Codeigniter 3. Just including the parent file is enough.

```
require_once(APPPATH."controllers/MyParentController.php");
class MyChildController extends MyParentController {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

All classes you are extending should live in application/CORE directory so in your case both My_Controller and Profile should live there. All "end point" controllers will live in application/controllers folder

**UPDATE**

I stand corrected. Extended classes should live in the same file. @Rooneyl's answer shows how to implement

Comment: I think is not necesary that all the controllers are under CORE but only the base controllers.

Comment: @luso, I tried putting my_controllers in /controllers/core and Profile & OtherClass (op called it Index) in /controllers. Otherclass extends Profile extends My_controller. that throws error. Move Profile to /core and it works. Are you able to put Profile & OtherClass in /controllers and get it to work?

Comment: @Alexey Gerasimov I've moved Profile class to the application/core folder, but nothing have changed. I do recieve the same error. Does it matter what name have file or anything else? What have I missed?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627587/code-igniter-2-how-to-extend-ci-controller-multiple-times/7627642#7627642 and http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY

Comment: @Rooneyl I got it. But is it a good practise to create an `__autoload` function, or better place all common classes in MY_Controller?

Comment: @Yekver Just me me, I tend to extend the core files in the way I described. Autoload in on the way out (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), and I don't want to redo things. I'm too lazy!

Comment: is not app/controllers/core but /app/core

Answer (score -1):

After some struggle with version 3 and this issue I decided this was not a bad solution...

```
require_once BASEPATH.'core/Controller.php';
require_once APPPATH.'core/MYCI_Controller.php';
```

to add this second line where the first exists in the system/core/CodeIgniter.php

*[If it's not too late, I recommend strongly against php and/or CodeIgniter.]*

Comment: Comment the reason before down voting.

Comment: It's likely they love php, my apologies if I've offended anyone.

Comment: They don't love PHP... Not all frameworks provide file handling and always need improvement.