# Codeigniter 3 - Extend CI_Controller inside 'controllers' folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, continuous-integration, extends

I'd like to extend `CI_Controller` further, but within the *controllers* folder.

I already have a subclass `MY_Controller` in *application/core/MY_Controller.php*, and I know already I can add new subclasses of `MY_Controller` in the same file.

**My question is, how to extend `MY_Controller` further by adding files in the *controllers* folder?**
For example:

```
class Comm_Controller extends MY_Controller{}

class ServiceA_Controller extends MY_Controller{}
// or even
class ServiceAplus_Controller extends ServiceA_Controller{}
```

If I do not modify the autoload, it will report **"class ServiceA_Controller not found"**, but I would prefer not to add any other file to the *application/core/* folder.

Comment: You don't need to add 'subclasses', but you need to add new files in core directory. CodeIgniter reads files/classes from core directory, not from controllers directory. Check code in `BASEPATH . 'core/CodeIgniter.php'` file around line 370 I'd say. Other way to use it is composer autoloading classes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extending The Controller Class in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342232/extending-the-controller-class-in-codeigniter)

Comment: @Abdulla That solution must put the base controller in core/ file. I've already mentioned.

Comment: @Tpojka Put the business code in core may be a little inelegant?

Comment: @Rex Otherwise you need to make your own bridge for wanted solution. I showed you snippet location where CI takes it from. If you don't like CI's logic of files/directories organization, you would be liking to use some other FW or solution. Aside that, I can't see one reason for avoiding core or library directory.

Comment: Thanks @Tpojka. I think I need HMVC support for CI.