# Codeigniter - How to load some code on every page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new with Codeigniter(CI) and playing with codes but I need some guidance to make this things complete.

Let's say I have written this code to with some conditions:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["lang"]) && !empty($_COOKIE["lang"])){
    if($_COOKIE["lang"] == "en"){
        $this->lang->load('en', 'english');
    }else{
        $this->lang->load('du', 'dutch');
    }
}else{
    $cookie = array(
                'name'   => 'lang',
                'value'  => 'en',
                'expire' => 604800
            );
    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
}
```

Now I want to load this code on every page to check which language file to  load.

I have tried with this way:

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    if(isset($_COOKIE["lang"]) && !empty($_COOKIE["lang"])){
        if($_COOKIE["lang"] == "en"){
            $this->lang->load('en', 'english');
        }else{
            $this->lang->load('du', 'dutch');
        }
    }else{
        $cookie = array(
                    'name'   => 'lang',
                    'value'  => 'en',
                    'expire' => 604800
                );
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
    }

}
```

but If I have lots of controller file so I can't go to change each an every file. Is there any simple way to manage at one place in codeigniter.

Comment: Extend the controller. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342232/extending-the-controller-class-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using CI [Hooks](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html)

Make sure you enable hooks in **application/config/config.php** :

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;

$hook['pre_controller'] = function()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    if(isset($_COOKIE["lang"]) && !empty($_COOKIE["lang"])){
        if($_COOKIE["lang"] == "en"){
            $CI->lang->load('en', 'english');
        }else{
            $CI->lang->load('du', 'dutch');
        }
    }else{
        $cookie = array(
            'name'   => 'lang',
            'value'  => 'en',
            'expire' => 604800
        );
        $CI->input->set_cookie($cookie);
    }
};
```