# Extending controller class in the same file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I write the following code but when i try access employee class it shows error message

```
class users extends CI_controller{
      function _construct(){
               parent::_construct();
                            }
                                }
class employee extends users{
                       }
```

Comment: add error message to question

Comment: You write all the code in one file?

Comment: plz complete error?

Comment: @mrdagon. I can't access employee controller

Comment: @FastSnail 
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
10q

Comment: @HizClick and what is the url you type

Comment: @FastSnail http://localhost/MMS/employee MMS is my base folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending The Controller Class in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342232/extending-the-controller-class-in-codeigniter)

Comment: @RyanVincent 10q. But my question is how controller class can inherit from another controller class

Comment: @RyanVincent thank you. But I need to create user control class to access it. am write?

Comment: No, the controller can execute whatever it wants to. If it wants to use a 'particular user model' then it loads it. see : [Loading a Model](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#id4) It is 'in charge' of what runs and in what order. However, it doesn't know about the details of 'users' unless it needs to. Likewise, the users doesn't know why it was loaded - it just has to do what it was asked to do. i.e. Neither extends the other? The 'user' should not even know a 'controller' exists. It just gets it's methods called from 'somewhere'.

Comment: @RyanVincent thank you again.  here is what i attempt to do now   class log extends CI_controller { ....}, class user{....}, class employee extends user{ }.

Answer (score 0):

basically codeigniter only pick one class into one controller . it better to use a helper in which you define your class and then load helper and then call your methods within controller

Comment: Sorry I don't get your point. could show me example thank you