# In Codeigniter extends one controller into another controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter(3.1.5) and Ihave two controllers in my application/controllers/ folder. with name controller A and Controller B. I want to extends Controller A in Controller B so that I can use methods of Controller A. But it generates class not found error.

Here is my sample code:

A_Controller.php:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class A_Controller extends CI_Controller {
  public function index()
  {
  }

  public function display(){
     echo 'base controller function called.';
  }
 }
```

B_Controller.php:

```
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class B_Controller extends A_Controller {

 }
```

I want to execute display() method of controller A in controller B.
If i put controller A in application/core/ folder and in application/config/config.php file make

> $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'A_';

then I can able to access methods of controller A.

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending The Controller Class in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342232/extending-the-controller-class-in-codeigniter)

Comment: CI so ugly to me, but then again most frameworks are...

Answer (score 3):

Extending a controller in another controller is not really good. Building with MVC and especially with CI, you have other options to achieve this.

1. Use a class `MY_Controller` inside `application/core` that extends the `CI_Controller`. Later, all (or some) of your controllers should extend the `MY_Controller`. In MY_Controller you can have many functions and you can call which function you want in your controller.
2. Use a library. Write your own library in `application/libraries` and load it in your controller wherever you want. A library is a class with functionality for your project.
3. Use a helper. Write your own helper in `application/helpers` and load it in your controller. A helper should have a general purpose for your application.

   In that way, your code will be more flexible and reusable for the future. Messing with 2 Controllers seems bad to me. Remember that with the default Routing system of CI you can be confused.

Comment: Yes, you told me standard way but in my case I want to inherit properety of base class into child class just for multisite pupose. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following code.

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
     class B_Controller extends A_Controller {
        public function test()
        {
            $this->display();
        }
     }
```

Comment: thanks for reply... but problem is differrent, it gives 'Class not found' error to extends A_Controller.

Answer (score 1):

add this script in B_Controller :

```
include_once (dirname(__FILE__) . "/A_Controller.php");
```

for example B_Controller.php :

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
include_once (dirname(__FILE__) . "/A_Controller.php");
class B_Controller extends A_Controller {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use construct in controller

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class B_Controller extends A_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
    }
    public function test()
    {
        $this->display();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using including parent controller on child controller like this -

`require_once(APPPATH."modules/frontend/controllers/Frontend.php");`

then my function like this -

```
class Home extends Frontend {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() {
        echo $this->test(); //from Frontend controller
    }

}
```

I hope this will help.