# codeigniter 404 not found when submiting form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, submit, http-status-code-404

I know this question has already been asked like a thousand time but i really tried and I don't succeed to correct this issue.

So when i submit my registration form, i got the 404 error, but the controller/function path is correct so I don't understand why I have this error.

registration form:

```
<section class='container'>
<?php 
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->helper('captcha');

$attributs = array('class' => 'col-md-12 col-xs-12', 'id' => 'inscription');
echo form_open('AjouterUtilisateur/ajouter', $attributs);
echo "Nom <br>".form_input('nom','test')."<br>";
echo "Prénom <br>".form_input('prenom','test')."<br>";
echo "Age <br>".form_input('age','test')."<br>";
echo "Pseudo <br>".form_input('pseudo','test')."<br>";
echo "Email <br>".form_input('email','test')."<br>";
echo "Mot de passe <br>".form_password('mdp','test')."<br>";
echo "Confirmation <br>".form_password('mdpConf','test')."<br>";
$bouton = array(
    'name' => 'button',
    'class' => 'button'
);
echo "<br>".form_submit($bouton, 'Valider !');
echo form_close();
?>
</section>
```

Adding controller:

```
class AjouterUtilisateur extends Utilisateur
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->Pseudo=$_POST['pseudo'];
        $this->Email=$_POST['email'];
        $this->Nom=$_POST['nom'];
        $this->Prenom=$_POST['prenom'];
        $this->Age=$_POST['age'];
        $this->MDP=$_POST['mdp'];

        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->db->close();
    }

    public function ajouter()
    {
        $donnees= array('Nom' => $Nom, 'Prenom' => $Prenom, 'Age' => $Age, 'Pseudo' => $Pseudo,'Email' => $Email, 'MDP' => $MDP,);
        $req = $this->db->insert_string('utilisateurs', $donnees);
        $query = $this->db->query('$req');
        if($query==FALSE)
            redirect(base_url('/pages/err'), 'refresh');
        else
            redirect(base_url('/pages/accueil'), 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Comment: `AjouterUtilisateur extends Utilisateur` it should extend CI_Controller

Comment: 'Utilisateur extends CI_Controller' and 'AjouterUtilisateur extends Utilisateur' so i think it's allright no ?

Comment: I would change the name of the controller and only have the first letter upper case same with file name and class name Ajouterutilisateur.php etc case sensitive codeigniter is

Comment: well @RemiHirtz try reading this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982187/codeigniter-extending-common-controller

Comment: You also may need to include the index.php in `form_open('index.php/ajouterutilisateur/ajouter);`

Comment: try also `var_dump(form_open('AjouterUtilisateur/ajouter');`

Comment: In `ajouter()` method put `echo '1';exit;` and see if you can go to that url without the form.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I followed all your tips (tahnks for that ;)) and know I have "Class 'MY_Utilisateur' not found" error, and I don't see what I did wrong.

In core/MY_Utilisateur

```
class MY_Utilisateur extends CI_Controller{
    protected $ID;
    protected $Pseudo;
    protected $Email;
    protected $Nom;
    protected $Prenom;
    protected $Age;
    protected $MDP;
    protected $DateInscription;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

In controllers/Ajouterutilisateur.php:

```
class Ajouterutilisateur extends MY_Utilisateur
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->Pseudo=$_POST['pseudo'];
        $this->Email=$_POST['email'];
        $this->Nom=$_POST['nom'];
        $this->Prenom=$_POST['prenom'];
        $this->Age=$_POST['age'];
        $this->MDP=$_POST['mdp'];

        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->db->close();
    }

    public function ajouter()
    {
        $donnees= array('Nom' => $Nom, 'Prenom' => $Prenom, 'Age' => $Age, 'Pseudo' => $Pseudo,'Email' => $Email, 'MDP' => $MDP,);
        $req = $this->db->insert_string('utilisateurs', $donnees);
        $query = $this->db->query('$req');

        if($query==FALSE)
            redirect(base_url('/pages/err'), 'refresh');
        else
            redirect(base_url('/pages/accueil'), 'refresh');
    }
}
```